# How to copy without losing selection javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am using a code in which it inserts a text containing the url of the current page after the person copies the selection (ctrl-c) and does this in a hidden part of the page, however when the person presses ctrl-c the selection some, would you have some way to copy and include the url of the current page without losing the selection? Sorry for the english, it was translated via google translator

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
 function addLink() {
    //Get the selected text and append the extra info
    var selection = window.getSelection(),
        pagelink = '<br /><br /> Read more at: ' + document.location.href,
        copytext = selection + pagelink,
        newdiv = document.createElement('div');

    //hide the newly created container
    newdiv.style.position = 'absolute';
    newdiv.style.left = '-99999px';

    //insert the container, fill it with the extended text, and define the new selection
    document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
    newdiv.innerHTML = copytext.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
    selection.selectAllChildren(newdiv);

    //remove a novadiv
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        document.body.removeChild(newdiv);
    }, 100);
}
document.addEventListener('copy', addLink);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='perg'>Text to copy</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you want.  I actually created a div (displayed) that is just static and not dynamically created like you have for demo purposes.  If I understand correctly you want to keep the current selection selected while copying the text and the location href to that div ?  If you want the text you actually can use .toString(), and in your code, when you use selection.selectAllChildren you are deselecting the text that you copied from.  Hard to undestand really exactly what you are asking.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
 
 function addLink() {
 
      let hiddendiv = document.getElementById('copiedstuff');
      let selection = window.getSelection();
     let selectiontext = window.getSelection().toString();
      pagelink = '<br /><br /> Read more at: ' + document.location.href;
      copytext = selectiontext + pagelink;
     hiddendiv.innerHTML = copytext.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");

}
document.addEventListener('copy', addLink);

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id='perg'>Text to copy</div>
<div id='perg1'>Something Else</div>
<div style = "margin-top:20px;border:1px solid black;">
<div id='copiedstuff'></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the contribution, but that's not what I need.
What I want to do is to copy the text + url from the current page, however keeping the selection, in the code that you included it copies the text but does not copy the url of the current page